# ajax fail recursive pure javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, recursion, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

```
var object = {
    ver: "version",
    time: "time",
    xhr: new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method: "POST",
    error: JSON.stringify({
        api: object.ver,
        err: "server",
        time: object.time
    });
},
servers = {
    srv1:"http://srv1.example.com",
    srv2:"http://srv2.example.com",
    srvErr:"http://err.example.com"
},
data = JSON.stringify({
    api: object.ver,
    time: object.time
});

function cors(object, server) { // Cross domain XHR request
    if ("withCredentials" in object.xhr) {
        object.xhr.open(object.method, server, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        object.xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        object.xhr.open(object.method, server);
    } else {
        object.xhr = null;
    }
    return object.xhr;
}
function ajax(data, object, server, servers) {;
    try {
        var x = cors(object, server);
        x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8", 'X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        x.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (x.readyState != 4) {
                return;
            }
            if(x.status==200){
                console.log("success: ", data);
            }
            n++;
            if (x.status != 200) {
                console.log("2", data);

                ajax(data, object, servers.srv2, server);
                //second call

                ajax(object.error, object, servers.srvErr, servers);
                //third call
            }
        };
        x.send(data);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}
ajax(data, object, servers.srv1, servers); // first call
```

I try to make two async ajax calls inside ajax call to my own servers, in case of outer ajax call did not succeed. I get result, that only last ajax call is really goes out of browser to the server. I can't use callback, as I only need this two ajax calls in case first one fail.

The main trick - I can't use jQuery, and this ajax should be cross-browser compatible -> IE8,9. I already test it on my servers, and it work with cross domain. the only thing is breaking my mind, how to make this code to run 2 ajax calls on fail of first one. I do not need COMET( subscribe) or WebSockets.

Please help me somebody.

Comment: I simplified the code and put here all my functions

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to modify your program follow to behave as you expect it to:

```
...
if (x.status != 200) {
    console.log("t2", d, "N: ", n);

    // I SUPPOSE HERE'S THE RIGHT PLACE TO INCREMENT YOUR COUNTER
    n++;

    try {
        f(d); // throw error with data json
    } catch (e) {
        a(e.message, p, r.t1, r, n);
    }
    try {
        e(p, s, r); // throw error with error json
    } catch (e) {
        a(e.message, p, r.err, r, n);
    }
}
....
```

You currently experience an unexpected behaviour because the `n` you see in the case of a request that returns with an error was updated in a wrong context.

Comment: no, this doesn't help - problem is not limiting ajax calls - if I will limit it to 100, there is only 2nd try/cach ajax call is making x.status == 200
first one is ignored.

Comment: I understood the count should matter if the first call failed, and with one success in less than 3 attempts the procedure should conclude. It's pointless counting attempts, when you're all done with the whole process.

Comment: Anyway, I can't say what you're doing is very clear to me. But I hope you figure it out. Cheers

Comment: there is 3 servers to send a call - 1st default, second - spare, and third - error notification. I need to have a call to error notification server each time when default and spare ajax call fails. so it is maximum 4 calls - 1 default, 1 spare, and 2 error. I do not need to leep callc running after fourth, so this is a limit counter function. Problem is with 2 ajax calls inside the fail block

Comment: can you describe the said problem more?